# Como mover un formulario a la zona derecha de la pantalla

Tags: html5, css

Hola amigos e estado buscando sobre este problema que me confunde mucho porque estoy empezando con esto por eso lo siento si el codigo no es de calidad.

mi problema es que tengo que move un formulario de contacto pero en realidad no se me viene nada a la mente de como hacerlo.

alguien me podria ayudar? ya tengo casi todo terminado solo me falta eso.

Codigo:

por ahi encontre que con la regla css position se podia pero no encuentro nada valioso.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Contacto</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    
    body{
   background-image:url(img/IMG_0139.JPG/);


    }
</style>
<body>

</body>
</html>

<?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
    {
    ?>
   <div style=" position:relative;" class="container">
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input for="usr" type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
    Tu nombre:<br>
    <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Tu email:<br>
    <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
     Tu Direccion:<br>
    <input name="direccion" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
    Tu mensaje:<br>
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    } 
else                /* send the submitted data */
    {
    $name=$_REQUEST['name'];
    $direccion=$_REQUEST['direccion']
    $email=$_REQUEST['email'];
    $message=$_REQUEST['message'];
    if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
        {
  echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again.";
     }
    else{  
     $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        $subject="CONTACTO CABALLO :)";
   mail("example@gmail.com", $subject, $message,$direccion $from);
  echo "Email sent!";
     }
    }  
?>
```

Comment: añadir la clase `pull-right` al contenedor `<div class="pull-right">`

Answer (score 2):

en el div anterior a form ponlo como sigue:

```
<div style="position:absolute;right: 0;" class="container">
```

Answer (score 1):

Con bootstrap (veo que lo estás usando) podés situarlo dentro de una columna con el ancho específico agregando la clase col-md-x donde x representa el entero del 1 al 12 que identifica el ancho de la columna.

Una vez hecho esto, debés completar el ancho del contenido con el espacio faltante:

```
<div class="col-md-6"></div> <!-- Columna vacía -->
<div class="col-md-6"><!-- Columna derecha con formulario -->
    <form  action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input for="usr" type="hidden" name="action" value="submit">
        Tu nombre:<br>
        <input name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
        Tu email:<br>
        <input name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
        Tu Direccion:<br>
        <input name="direccion" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
        Tu mensaje:<br>
        <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Send email"/>
    </form>
</div>
```